# Report Properties - Visual Studio 2019

Tags: reporting-services, visual-studio-2019

I'm simply trying to find where I can change report properties associated with how the report would be printed (margins, landscape option, etc.). I know it's via the Report Properties option, but I can't find this anywhere.

Answer (score 5):

Click a blank area of the report outside  the report body and then hit F4. This will give you the report properties.

Note that within the report is the report body which also has it's own dimension properties. To get to this click the "background" of the report that contains all the report controls.

Answer (score 2):

From the Solution Explorer open rdlc report. then click Extensions from main menu click Report and click Report properties.